# Overflow error whenever clicking button to save data in access

Tags: vb.net-2010

Can any one help me
I have a form through which I am saving date in my ms access database.
some times I click save button the data save correctly but some times it gives me error **"overflow" 'ExecuteNonQuery' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.**
I am using this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Add Data?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "WARNING") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Dim OleDBC As New OleDbCommand
        With OleDBC

            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "Insert Into tblmaritlistBA_I (form_number,name_of_candidate,fathers_name,mothers_name,category,minority,date_of_birth,gender,mobile,address,board,passed_year,intermediate_marks_obtained,intermediate_total_marks,percentage,normalization_factor,total_percentage)  VALUES ('" & txtformnumber.Text & "','" & txtstuname.Text & "','" & txtfathname.Text & "','" & txtmothname.Text & "','" & cmbcategory.Text & "','" & cmbminority.Text & "','" & dobPicker1.Text & "','" & cmbgender.Text & "','" & txtmobile.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & cmbboard.Text & "','" & cmbpassedyear.Text & "','" & txtintermarks.Text & "','" & txtintertotalmarks.Text & "','" & txtpercentage.Text & "','" & Lblnormalization.Text & "','" & txtpercentageafterN.Text & "')"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("Data Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")
        Me.Hide()

        Call initgrid()
    End If
End Sub
```

kindly help me ("_")

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you never opened your database connection.

You set `conn` to be the connection of the `Command` object but you never instantiated it first nor opened it.

See the code below. The `Connection` object is created (put your own connection string in), then it is opened.

At the very end that connection must be closed in a `Finally` block, so that we close it even on an error

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Try
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Add Data?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "WARNING") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            conn = New OleDbConnection("YOUR_CONNECTIONSTRING_HERE")
            conn.Open()

            Dim OleDBC As New OleDbCommand

            With OleDBC
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "Insert Into tblmaritlistBA_I (form_number,name_of_candidate,fathers_name,mothers_name,category,minority,date_of_birth,gender,mobile,address,board,passed_year,intermediate_marks_obtained,intermediate_total_marks,percentage,normalization_factor,total_percentage)  VALUES ('" & txtformnumber.Text & "','" & txtstuname.Text & "','" & txtfathname.Text & "','" & txtmothname.Text & "','" & cmbcategory.Text & "','" & cmbminority.Text & "','" & dobPicker1.Text & "','" & cmbgender.Text & "','" & txtmobile.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & cmbboard.Text & "','" & cmbpassedyear.Text & "','" & txtintermarks.Text & "','" & txtintertotalmarks.Text & "','" & txtpercentage.Text & "','" & Lblnormalization.Text & "','" & txtpercentageafterN.Text & "')"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            MsgBox("Data Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")
            Me.Hide()

            Call initgrid()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error : " & ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If (conn.state and ConnectionState.Open) <>0 Then 
            conn.Close 
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: @SantoshPandey did that fix your issue? If so please mark the answer as checked, otherwise let me know what if any issue you are still having